# Embedding private youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a youtube account with some private videos and I want to embed those private videos in my website. Only users who are registered with my website and are logged in to my website should be able to see/play those videos. Also, It is required that they should not be able to open the video using the link in another tab without logging into my website, thus keeping the videos as unlisted is not an option. Any ideas? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, when a video is private on YouTube, only you can see the video.
Plus once the video is private you cannot emebed the video.

> The video requested was not found. This error occurs when a video has been removed (for any reason) or has been marked as private.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

The only solution you have is to not use YouTue service but upload directly the video on your server and use the default HTML5 player. This way you can manage that only connected user can view the videos.